# How to print Stack in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, stack, jlabel

I have a method that prints a stack, however, it prints via System.out.println and I need to print it to a JLabel instead, so that it's visible in my GUI.

I'm using the UI designer from Netbeans, so I have a JFrame file, a main class file, and a stack file where I wrote the showStack method.
"Pila" is a class that extends Stack.

This is the method

```
public void showStack(Pila<Integer> s){  
        if (s.isEmpty())  
            return;  

        Integer x = s.peek();  
        s.pop();  
        showStack(s);  

        System.out.print(x + " ");  
        s.push(x);  
    }
```

I want to get rid of the System.out.print and replace it with something I could use to print the stack in a Jlabel

Comment: A JLabel shows one line of text only -- is this what you want? I would think that you would want to print the stack as a column of text, such as in a JList.

Comment: OK, any way is fine, I'm very new to GUI building so if a Jlist is better, I'll go with it.

Comment: Then best that you struggle with a solution first rather than ask others to give your code or even give a push in the right direction. Go for it, and good luck

Comment: Then please show us your GUI attempt in your question [edit]. This will greatly improve the quality of the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a function that returns a String, and put that String on your label's text. I think it would work with the same code you have for your console prints, but concatenating it in a String instead of printing it

```
String output; // this one is to concatenate your String
public String returnStack(Pila<Integer> s){
    if (s.isEmpty())  {
        return "";
    }

    Integer x = s.peek();  
    s.pop();  
    showStack(s);  

    output+= x + " ";  
    s.push(x);
    return output;
}
```